# Using split to split up data and store in matrix

Tags: java, split

My program reads a data file line by line and each line is read as a string. Here is an example of one line:

13 0 150801 00010860 04 04 1 076 2270 999 2 0 1 0 16 04 07 054 0311 068 0135 064 0533 079 0139 075 0640 079 0135 088

I now need to split this string where there are spaces. I have written the following code, but get an error when I run it. Here is the code:

//Matrix to store the WIM data
                    String[][] WIMdataMatrix = new String[WIMdataList.size()][30];

```
                //Splits the string lines in different elements and stores in matrix
                for(int i = 0 ; i < WIMdataList.size() ; i++){

                    String[] temp = WIMdataList.get(i).split(" ");

                    for(int j = 0 ; j < 30 ; j++){

                        WIMdataMatrix[i][j] = temp[j];
                    }
                }
```

And here is the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 8
    at wim_data_reader.WIMdataReader.main(WIMdataReader.java:61)
```

If I understand correct, it means that I am trying to access the matrix in an element that is not in the size I specified, please help!

Comment: 30 seems to be number defined by you, try temp.length

Comment: Stick to the Java Naming Conventions! Variables always start with lowercase letters! (Except for constants.)

Answer (score 5):

change to

```
for(int j = 0 ; j < 30 && j < temp.length; j++){
```

to ensure that the `temp` array size is not being exceeded

Comment: Thank you very much, I just used temp.length and everything runs.

Comment: BTW as your array is limited to 30, you should also check as per answer, as if `temp.length` were to exceed the array size, you will also run into an error.